# ASP.Net Single Sign On CrossDomain with OneLogin and DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net, cross-domain, single-sign-on, onelogin

I'm working on a project requiring single sign on cross-domain (not subdomain) authentication for 2 websites.

I've search for what others have said around here and on the web and tried to use DotNetOpenAuth but I can't make much sense of it and the documentation is not helping much. So I turned to [OneLogin](http://www.onelogin.com/) which seems to provide what I want but again, the documentation is lacking. I think I have to use both of them but I can't connect the pieces of the puzzle.

I'm getting closer to implement my own SSO solution based on [Single Sign-On Enterprise Security for Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972971.aspx) but want to avoid that as it'd take much more time and be more bug prone than using an existing solution..

So now for some questions for all the gurus out there:

1. Can you shed some light on how to use DotNetOpenAuth to authenticate users in OneLogin?
2. Where can I get some more examples for OneLogin?
3. Regarding DotNetOpenAuth for those who have tried the VS2010 project template, did that compiled or was missing the RelyingPartyLogic.dll? Where can I get that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

DotNetOpenAuth supports OpenID, OAuth, and InfoCard. The OneLogin SAML toolkit is for web based-sso with SAML. These two libraries will not work together.

For more information on the OneLogin .NET toolkit I can recommend this article
https://onelogin.zendesk.com/entries/20186386-introduction-to-onelogin-s-saml-toolkits

DotNetOpenAuth will help you do what you want to do provided you can support OpenID from your 2 websites; however, my recommendation is for you to look into the SAML family of protocols (wikipedia has a good article on this) You need to implement an identity provider (the site that authenticates you), and the consumer (the site you access).

You might want to look at a comparison between OpenID and SAML in order to choose which is better for you. Here is further reading that can help with that:
https://onelogin.zendesk.com/entries/270738-openid-or-saml-for-enterprise-sso